# Again, "AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'query' "

Tags: attributes, attributeerror

I tried to replicate the "SQLAlchemy Application" example on the https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html. All the three files are the same as those on that link. However, when I ran the app.py file, I get the error message: AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'query'.

Similar questions have been asked on the forum before. I tried all those suggested solutions and still get the error message.

Please help and thanks.

Comment: The example is the "Basic SQLAlchemy Application with session" example. It has three files: app.py, database.py, and models.py.

Comment: Ok, I figured out the problem: there was a typo in the codes I typed. Thanks.